# How do I contact a moderator?

Tags: support

I tried finding this moderator who moved my question on "chat", but no luck. I visited his profile in hopes to find a "contact mod" button, no luck. I even tried to add a comment in my original question at Math Stackexchange, no luck. I added a comment at the new location, but I don't think any moderator has read my question over there, so I am totally out of luck.

My questions asked for some advice on graduate school specifically for math and not that I am question the quality of answers over at the new location, but I wanted mostly opinions from mathematicians.

My question got migrated to another area where it is a "beta" and there doesn't seem to be much activity going on there.

Here was the original question https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/a-comprehensive-question-about-personal-statement

Thank you very much for reading

Comment: I do not really think that the question belongs here. There *is* a significant number of math people reading academia.SE, so you should just wait a bit.

Comment: (I tend not to like questions which look like hydras... it is much better (and much better adapted to the format of this site) to ask more focused questions. Your question has really way too many heads)

Comment: Sorry, I already know my question is long and I should be expecting  some time for an answer. I only made that remark because I was used to the plentiful activity in the regular math exchange. In the new location, I saw about one question getting one to two answers every 10 hours and the thought just frighten me that I will never get my question answered even if I put up a lot of bounties.

Comment: "In the new location, I saw about one question getting one to two answers every 10 hours" - that isn't a very long amount of time to wait. Some patience from your part would help you a good deal...

Comment: By the way, let me answer the question in the title: flag something (ideally, one of your questions or answers) and in the text of the flag ask us to contact you somehow for some reason.

Comment: I thought about doing that but I thought flagging was only reserved for reporting a problem relevant to that one question and I wasn't sure if flagging it at the new location will reach other mods. Thank you nonetheless

Comment: @Arthur, since the math mod room is inaccessible to non-mods, I'm not sure you can be easily pinged from the main math chatroom if you aren't there.

Comment: *I wanted mostly opinions from mathematicians.* I do not frequent academia.SE very often, bet there are certainly several mathematicians there. *there doesn't seem to be much activity going on there.* Well, the [site stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia) suggest that this is not an entirely accurate claim.

Comment: @J.M.   Hmmmm... my memory of past events might be inaccurate.

Comment: Somewhat related: [What are appropriate ways to contact moderators in different occasions? Flag, Comment, Chat, Email?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19850) and maybe also [Should we have “messages for moderators” chatroom?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19265)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My decision to migrate it was based on the following factors:

1. According to our [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic) the question was off-topic.
2. In my opinion the question had very little specific to *mathematics*, and with very few changes the same question could be asked about "physics" or "history".
3. The question was multiply flagged as *off-topic*.
4. You seemed to question its appropriateness to math.SE:

   > I hope this is not the wrong place to ask.
5. It *is* on-topic in the destination SE.

I also note that having good questions on beta sites will help those sites grow and attract more (and better qualified) users.  I do feel that it was a good question to ask, just not on the *math* Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for reading anyways. Sorry for asking this question then.

Comment: Don't worry about this question. It might actually attract some users to your question on academia.SE. I notice that it's been upvoted at least a couple times since the migration, and all this without any appropriate tags (I've submitted a re-tag edit there, but it needs to be approved before it is visible to all).