# Need moderation

Tags: support, moderators, moderation

Does anyone knows how can I contact privately a moderator ? Many of my answers have been deleted for no reason. Even upvoted and accepted answers. Always by the same three members. I have flagged as much as I can. But get no reaction. Thanks.

Comment: Try [math mods office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you Isabella for your comment. I will try that. Even though i have flagged all the deleted posts.

Comment: They have the option to create a private chat, I don't know about the details tho. I mean what 'private' implies

Comment: But remember, or in case you don't know yet, no one will get a notification (not even room owners) unless you ping

Comment: @Isabella  Ok thank you isabella. Very kind of you.

Comment: Is it always by the same 3 members? always _always_? if yes, then that's serious (you're a target sir lol) \\how many did they delete? Also, I'd be better (imo)  if you specify a little more, like if they deleted PSQ or weren't PSQ or were closed as [duplicated] or what

Comment: Yes always the same team same three members.  No the questions were not duplicate questions. And when a question is duplicate they dont delete it they close the question that's all. @Isabella It's really bothering me. Because I take time to answer. They deleted in less than a month ten questions. Last year i had no problem

Comment: "It's really bothering me. Because I take time to answer. They deleted in less than a month ten questions." Don't worry about it.  There are user out there that frequent [GENTLE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97476/gentle) and they save useful content on math.stack. You could go there and propose your deleted question and explain them all.

Comment: Not my questions. I have asked only two questions in more than two years here on Math SE. They deleted my answers when they delete the questions. But you're right there are many kind members here @Isabella

Comment: Related: [What are appropriate ways to contact moderators in different occasions? Flag, Comment, Chat, Email?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19850)

Comment: BTW it is unclear what you mean by " I have flagged ... But get no reaction." Were your flags not handled yet? Were they declined? If the flags have been handled, did you check whether a moderator left some message on the flag?

Comment: @MartinSleziak the problem is solved I got the answers I wanted. But thank you anyway for the link.

Comment: @LostInSpace I was checking Martin's link and I think your question is a duplicate of such. Check the first comment by Lord_Farin, it's what I told you to do

Comment: hi @Isabella Yes maybe it is. I didn't check before to post my question.